# If I can't use mailto protocol to open a mail with a html body, then how?

Tags: html, email, share, mailto, indexhibit

On my website I have a button that I hope visitors would use to share my content by mail.

It's simple, it uses the mailto protocol and it works.

However the message within the mail sucks because it's plain text.

I know there are emails with a html body that makes sharing stuff easier and you can add things like Twitter Cards, Facebook Open Graph and Google+ Markup.

However it seems the two doesn't combine or am I missing something?
I want to be able to send rich HTML emails using the mailto protocol.

I'm currently using a CMS-platform called indexhibit and simply changing to wordpress or something else is not an option.

Comment: You could try adding the code that currently sends the email to your question. People will be a lot more likely to help if you can provide a clear example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

No you aren't missing something, there is not really any reliable way to send HTML via the mailto protocol, it is essentially intended for short plain-text messages. Some clients *may* show HTML that is included but it isn't the usual case.

Really the best way for you to handle this would be to make a simple mailer script within indexhibit, written in php, that will allow you to send HTML in your emails.

If you google for "sending HTML emails with php" I am sure you will find lots of examples.